# Selenium Chrome webdriver SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

Using selenium & Chrome webdriver, I'm getting below exception on trying to launch. I have gone through lot of posts and tried all possible ways.
I'm using compatible chrome browser and chrome drivers versions -

- Version 80.
- Java - 1.8
- Windows 10 os

The same test when i run on my personal computer, its working. But it's giving below error on my organization s machine. Also, no issues if I use edge drivers.

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created 
disconnected: unable to send message to renderer
```

Any thoughts to solve this?

Comment: You need to show your code

Answer (score 0):

Check for chromedriver version in organization's machine. Please update your chromedriver with lastest version in organization machine. Issue will get resolve

Answer (score 0):

The ChromeDriver Version you are using in your code might be different than the Chrome Browser installed in your system.

Check and download the same version of driver as of your browser version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) (matching MAX number) with respect to the installed [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) version installed in your system.

As an example if you are using the current *`chrome=88.0.4324.104`* effectively you can use either of the following versions of **ChromeDriver**:

- [**ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.27**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=88.0.4324.27/)
- [**ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=88.0.4324.96/)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer with ChromeDriver 2.45 Chrome v71](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808653/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-from-disconnected-unab/53809634#53809634)
- [WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer even on providing correct path of latest chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55075864/webdriverexception-disconnected-unable-to-connect-to-renderer-even-on-providin/55075882#55075882)
- [Automation Testing Error : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642014/automation-testing-error-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-disconnected/48642804#48642804)