# Chrome Driver error selenium Message: session not created from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was using chrome webdriver in selenium.
I noticed that my chrome version is 88.0.4324.104, However, I am unable to find the exact version for chrome driver as all I can find is below version.
[image]

As this result, I got the following error when I run the script.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
```

from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer

I also read the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648667/selenium-chrome-webdriver-sessionnotcreatedexception), it has to be exactly the same version.

Can someone advise on this.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using *`chrome=88.0.4324.104`* you need to use the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) (matching the MAX version). So effectively you can use either of the following versions of **ChromeDriver**:

- [**ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.27**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=88.0.4324.27/)
- [**ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=88.0.4324.96/)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer with ChromeDriver 2.45 Chrome v71](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808653/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-from-disconnected-unab/53809634#53809634)
- [WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer even on providing correct path of latest chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55075864/webdriverexception-disconnected-unable-to-connect-to-renderer-even-on-providin/55075882#55075882)
- [Automation Testing Error : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642014/automation-testing-error-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-disconnected/48642804#48642804)

Comment: In fact, I tried both versions that you posted, it did not work for me.